# (Why) Is virtual base class constructor call required in pure virtual derived class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pure-virtual, virtual-inheritance

I have a class hierarchy with a **diamond** structure and a base class **without default constructor**, since it has reference members.

The code looks as follows:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base( CustomType& obj ) : refObj_( obj ) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
private:
    CustomType& refObj_;
};

class Left : public virtual Base
{
public:
    Left() {}; // ERROR: Compiler requests calling Base's constructor
    virtual void leftsMethod() = 0;
};

class Right : public virtual Base
{
public:
    Right( CustomType& obj ) : Base( obj ) {}; // Compiles, but Base( obj ) never gets called here
    virtual void rightsMethod() = 0;
};

class Bottom : public Left, public Right
{
public:
    Bottom( CustomType& obj ) : Base( obj ), Left(), Right( obj ) {}
};
```

**Edit**: Added virtual base destructor (original code has it)

Note that *Left* and *Right* are pure virtual classes, i.e. under no 
circumstances their constructors would call *Base*'s constructor.
This is due to virtual inheritance, implying that the most derived class *Bottom* calls *Base*'s constructor.

My question: Why do I nevertheless have to call *Base*'s constructor in the initialization list of *Left*? I'd like to avoid this and to pass the reference directly from *Bottom*'s constructor only to *Base*. (I'm using MSVC 2010s "half C++11" compiler.)

Is there another solution for this combination of virtual inheritance and references in the base class?

Comment: Consistency.   Humans would not expect adding or removing a `=0` to the declaration of an unrelated member function (i.e. toggling if that member function is pure virtual or not) to change how the compiler treats `Left`s constructor (e.g.  compiles the constructor definition if the function is pure virtual, but does not compile if the function is virtual but not pure).   Although, AFAIK, it's not a formal requirement of the standardisation process, few developers - including those on the standardisation committee - like the idea of a change of code causing something unrelated to break.

Comment: @Peter Thanks! That's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Due to that, better to have virtual base with only default constructor. Add interface (pure virtual method) instead of (non defaulted) members.

Comment: @Peter: As human, I found it more confusing to have initialization not called. That pure abstract class should not have to "call" virtual base class would be fine IMO.

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree. Base class is legacy code :(

Comment: @Jarod42 - the problem with requiring a virtual base to have only a default constructor is that a base class does not control if it is used as a virtual base.  It is the derived class that specifies if a base is virtual.     Having code for a base class suddenly not compile because some other code uses it as a virtual base would confuse people.   In any event, I was giving my interpretation as to why the behaviour is what it is, in response to a question.    If you want to argue that some other behaviour is better, contact a member of the standardisation committee, and make your case.

Comment: Actually, this code compiles just fine, starting with [clang 3.4.1](https://godbolt.org/z/oNa7dC), [gcc 7.1](https://godbolt.org/z/XEeVtZ), and all available (on godbolt.org) [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/Sp6iRS) versions. The issue OP describes occurs only in lower versions. Anyone knows what has changed? @staerkHelmis maybe just switch to a newer version of your compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design issues (which clearly exist here) aside, I fully agree with your reasoning that, because `Left` is an abstract class, no `Left` constructor will ever have to call any `Base` constructor and thus it is odd that it is required.

In fact, I tested your code with several compiler versions and **it does compile** just fine with [gcc 7.1](https://godbolt.org/z/XEeVtZ) and onwards, with [clang 3.4.1](https://godbolt.org/z/oNa7dC) and onwards, and with all available [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/Sp6iRS) versions.

So, my assumption is, that this was just a bug in earlier compiler versions. Can anyone confirm this?

Also note, if you change `virtual void leftsMethod() = 0;` to `virtual void leftsMethod() {}`, so that `Left` is not abstract anymore, the error returns, even with the [latest versions](https://godbolt.org/z/KLXw5I). And this makes perfectly sense, as now you **could** instantiate a `Left` instance and thus it would be up to `Left`'s constructor to call one of `Base`'s constructors.

### Possible workaround

If you cannot switch to a newer compiler and if you cannot alter the implementation of `Base`, this may be a working solution for you:

Define a dummy instance of `CustomType` somewhere. Then, you can provide the "required" default constructors like this:

```
class CustomType{};

class Base
{
public:
    Base( CustomType& obj ) : refObj_( obj ) {}
private:
    CustomType& refObj_;
};

static CustomType dummy;

class Left : public virtual Base
{
protected:
    Left() : Base(dummy) {}; // note here
public:
    virtual void leftsMethod() = 0;
};

class Right : public virtual Base
{
protected:
    Right() : Base(dummy) {}; // and here
public:
    virtual void rightsMethod() = 0;
};

class Bottom : public Left, public Right
{
public:
    Bottom( CustomType& obj ) : Base( obj ), Left(), Right() {}
    virtual void leftsMethod() override {}
    virtual void rightsMethod() override {}
};

void test()
{
    CustomType c;
    Bottom b(c);
}
```

This is just to make the compiler happy, your argument that these constructors will never call `Base(dummy)` still holds.

Note however, that `Base` should really have a virtual destructor! I don't know if you just didn't include it here for brevity or if it really doesn't have one. If it doesn't, it's a very bad idea to build a class hierarchy on top of it.

Comment: You're right, I added the destructor which the original (legacy) base class has. I also thought about your workaround and consider it best under the constraints I have.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a default constructor for `Base`, but `Left` still needs to initialize one when you create a `Left` object (one that is not a `Bottom` one).

The issue is that you have a reference in `Base` which means that you don't have a simple constructor possible.

I would say that you have a big design problem, as `obj` is initialized by `Right`, so the latter should hold `obj`, not `Base`.

Also where is the virtual destructor for `Base`?

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
    ~Base() {}
};

class Left : public virtual Base
{
public:
    virtual void leftsMethod();
};

class Right : public virtual Base
{
    int& refObj_;
public:
    Right( int& obj ) : refObj_( obj ) {}
    virtual void rightsMethod();
};

class Bottom : public Left, public Right
{
public:
    Bottom( int& obj ) : Right( obj ) {}
};
```

Comment: That's not my point, sorry I should have clarified this. A default constructor is not approriate because it could only set the reference with another dummy member. Even this default constructor would never be called, so I'm wondering why it has to be implemented.

Comment: But someone could inherit from `Left` and you would need to initialise the reference. C++ is not working as you think it does.

Comment: Someone who inherits, say LeftDrc, from Left would have to call Base's constructor (implicitly or explicitly). LeftDrc would be forced to call the non-default constructor of Base, just as one is forced to do so if one directly inherits from Base.

Comment: *"`obj` is initialized by `Right`"*. No, it is initialized by `Bottom`, that's the OP's point. OP's problem is that it has to write abstract derived classes as `Right` instead of simply `Left`.

Comment: OK, that clarifies the question. Still seems to me like a bad design in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A quote from the official docs may describe the situation:

> Practically speaking, this means that when you create a concrete class that has a virtual base class, you must be prepared to pass whatever parameters are required to call the virtual base class’s constructor. And, of course, if there are several virtual base classes anywhere in your classes ancestry, you must be prepared to call all their constructors. This might mean that the most-derived class’s constructor needs more parameters than you might otherwise think.

See this [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-ctors).

Comment: The reason for the failure is that there is a reference to initialise in `Base` when initializing `Left`. So no default constructor. Otherwise, it would be fine.